# while using Spring ApplicationContext as in the example below, are annotations taken care of

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-annotations

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    public WaterContainer wc;

    private static int count = 0;

    SomeClass(){ ++count;}

    public static int testmethod() {
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring-configuration\\beans.xml");

        SomeClass obj = context.getBean(SomeClass.class);
        //SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass();
        System.out.println("value of count "+SomeClass.testmethod());
        if(obj.wc != null)
            System.out.println("wc volume "+obj.wc.getCurrentVolume());
        else
            System.out.println("wc bean "+context.getBean(WaterContainer.class).getCurrentVolume()); //+(obj.wc==null)
    }
}
```

The beans.xml file contains this :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="com.app.data.SomeClass"/>
    <bean class="com.app.mechanism.WaterContainer">
        <constructor-arg value="30"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

the output that I got was as below but I expected the field wc in the SomeClass object to not be null, does that mean autowired annotations are not taken care of? or have I gone wrong somewhere? 
value of count 1 
wc bean 30

If so then how does 
`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:spring-configuration\\beans.xml"})` 
work for unit testing? how is the autowiring taken care of here

Comment: <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

Comment: If annotations are processed automatically depends on the type of `ApplicationContext` used. The one you use doesn't proces annotations, as you already noticed. To enable the annotation processing ass `<context:annotation-config />`. Or use an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and feed it the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

[As M. Deinum stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645681/while-using-spring-applicationcontext-as-in-the-example-below-are-annotations-t#comment40073844_25645681), annotation configuration is built into some `ApplicationContext` implementations and not in others.

`FileSystemXmlConfiguration` is an implementation that does not have annotation configuration built into it. You can enable that annotation configuration with

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

(and the relevant namespace declarations).

Since that configuration was not enabled, `@Autowired` fields were not processed, and your `SomeClass#wc` field was left `null`.

The test configuration you've shown internally uses an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` where annotation configuration *is* built in.

Comment: when I use the <context..> tags in xml, `wc` is not null for `obj` but when I use `obj2` `wc` is still null

Comment: @shrewquest I'm assuming you mean `//SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass();`. Notice how you are creating the object yourself. Spring is not involved in the least.